# Span a space for bunch of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean for a bunch of vectors to span a space?

Let Vector V1, V2, ........ Vn , Span a space means the space consist of all combination of those vectors.

How does a figure of span looks likes ?
I am not able to imagine.

Novice in Linear algebra. Please help if you think it's an appropriate question.
Thanks

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span for a start.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through the Wikipedia but I don't have much knowledge to understand the terms used in it. I just wanted a simple explanation

Comment: Start in low dimensions. What it means for one vector to span the real line? Then, what is the span of two vectors in the real plane?

Comment: One vector to span a real line would be a "Line". Span of two vectors in real plane would be a "Plane". But what about the higher dimensions?